# Detect last widget being deleted

Tags: android, android-widget

I created a widget which uses a background service for update notifications.

I want to stop the background service if the last widget is removed from the home screen(s).

How can I detect number of widgets remaining in home screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a way that doesn't involve having to store any persistent information. However even this looks like a hack to me. Inserted the following in the onReceive -

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(sIntentAction)) {
            AppWidgetManager amgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            int length = amgr.getAppWidgetIds(intent.getComponent()).length;
            if (length==0) WidgetService.StopService(context);
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

It works, and is the best solution I could find, but I am not very happy with it.

I needed to do this in `onReceive` and not `onDeleted`, since the `intent` object is required to do `intent.getComponent()`. I don't like the fact because the documentation claims that one will rarely need to touch the `onReceive`, and need to count remaining widgets seems to be a reasonable expectation in `onDeleted`. However unfortunately it provides count of widgets being deleted, and not count remaining. Is there any way to do this in the `onDeleted` instead?

(Slowly I seem to get the feeling that a lot of Android coding is actually hacking - and the code to get a job done mostly uses undocumented or unexpected avenues.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I agree with you on this being a hacky solution. However, we do what we need. In response to your final statement, I do not personally find that coding in Android is hacking (according to the connotation presented). I do, however, find that there is a lack of education when compared to the abundance of ingenuity that the community has. There are many ways to do almost everything in a very safe and technically correct manner, but there are not a lot of people who know how to do them. Time, effort and education will help this.

Comment: You're right, partly it is function of having the right kind of documentation. Yes, I guess as the community grows and matures the knowledgebase will also evolve.

Answer (score 1):

If you created a `AppWidgetProvider` for your `Widget`, it should have an `onUpdate()` method. One of the arguments for `onUpdate()` is the `int[] ids`. This is actually an array of all of the AppWidget instances receiving `onUpdate()` requests. If the size of `ids` is 1, then the next delete is your last widget. :)

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic

Comment: There's just one problem with this - the number of ids cannot be simply stored in a member variable, since the class will be destroyed after each update. Would you recommend I store them to a persistent storage?

Comment: No, you absolutely do not need them stored persistently. You can store the information that you need inside an extended Application object, or as the member of a static reference (be careful with the static reference though). Your solution below is also viable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my application and this is what I ended up doing to figure out if I had deleted the last widget or not, which allowed me to stop my service and update a preference item that was saved.

```
@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context)
{
    // When this get called I need to figure out how to set the preference 
    // homeWidgetSetup = false.
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context, BasicHomeWidget.class.getName());
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);

    if(appWidgetIds.length < 1)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Removed the last widget!");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, KMMDService.class);
        intent.putExtra("lastWidgetDeleted", true);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Then I just tested looked at the extra passed to my service on `onStartCommand` and if has "lastWidgetDeleted" defined as true then I would stop the service and update my preferences.

Answer (score 0):

may be answer is too late but onEnabled and onDisabled is called only when first widget is instantiated  and when last widget is removed for a particular appwidget provider. Hence the above hacky and other technecs are not required.

if still you have doubts please go through the [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onEnabled(android.content.Context))